# Crystal Reports, vb.net and dynamic pictures: wrong width unit measure in code

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm in trouble with dynamically loaded pictures in crystal reports.

I need to load a picture at runtime (via formula) and set its width in code.
In cr documentation is stated that object sizes, when accessed through code, are expressed in twips.

I found out that this is not true for dynamically loaded pictures.

Here are the steps to reproduce this issue:

- Create a "10cm.jpg" file with these specs:

  - width = 1181 px
  - height = 100 px
  - density = 300 dpi

This picture, when printed, will be 10 cm in width ((10 / 2.54) * 300 ~= 1181).

- Create a new report ("10cm.rpt").
- Insert "10cm.jpg".
- Set properties for this picture as follows:

  - object name = "MyPic1"
- Insert another picture (say 10x10, it doesn't really matter).
- Set properties for this picture as follows:

  - object name = "MyPic2"
  - Graphic location [X-2] (under "picture" tab) = "C:\Path\to\10cm.jpg"

This way the report contains two "copies" of the same picture, one embedded and one loaded at runtime.

- Now create a VB.NET / C# Windows Forms project and place a cr viewer and two buttons.

This is the relevant code:

```
Private report As New ReportDocument

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    report.Load("C:\Path\to\10cm.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault)

    viewer.ReportSource = report

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim MyPic1W = report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("MyPic1").Width ' 5669 <-- this is in twips and the value is OK: 1mm ~= 56.69 twips
    Dim MyPic2W = report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("MyPic2").Width ' 435 <- ????????????????????????  

End Sub ' Breakpoint here

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("MyPic1").Width = 8504 ' MyPic1 is correctly resized to 15 cm
    report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("MyPic2").Width = 8504 ' MyPic2 becomes really large!

    viewer.ReportSource = report

End Sub
```

As you can see in Button1_Click, width for MyPic1 is correctly expressed in twips, while for MyPic2 is expressed in a different unit.

Trying to set pictures width (Button2_Click) using twips is working for MyPic1, while MyPic2 becomes very large.
MyPic2 is resized correctly if I specify a value that is proportional to its unknown unit: if I set width to 435 * 1.5 ~= 653, its size correctly becomes 15cm.

Does someone know where this unit comes from?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that it is not a good idea to ask Crystal to resize images. It might spike rpt memory consumption.

It is better to resize the image outside Crystal and dynamically load the resulting file.

At least one of the UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) allows a Crystal formula to take care of the image resizing so the 'Graphic Location' expression in Crystal can resize (outside Crystal) and then load the image file. You can do the same in your code.